# Book where astronauts sent out to find other life are recalled back to Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I had a book in the 80's-90's that I would like to find a copy of if I could just remember the title/author. It was published in English.

Ships with lone astronauts had been sent out to explore for other life. The program is cancelled and a 'recall' is sent to the ships. The protagonist meets a shape-shifting alien named Protea (I believe) who is the only alien in the book. When they get back to Earth, all the other astronauts' ships are parked in orbit and they must battle another astronaut who is a sort of insane madman that has returned before them and killed all the other astronauts.

The alien (Protea) is written throughout the book as very feminine, although is (as I recall) largely portrayed as a sentient mist that can assume any shape.
At the end:

> the human astronaut and the alien are the only survivors and decide to leave Earth and return 'to the stars'. The alien ingests (eats) the human and then divides (rather like an amoeba) with each of their consciousness inhabiting one of the resulting mist bodies.

Comment: Goodbye, moon men.